# Why is my token classified as ERC721 instead of ERC20?

Tags: blockchain, erc-20, erc-721

I created an ERC20 token using the ERC20Interface, but it's classified as ERC721 on the Mumbai polygon scan. What can be the reason?

```
interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
    function name() external view returns (string memory);
    function getOwner() external view returns (address);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 indexed value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 indexed value);
}

contract MyToken is IERC20 {
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping (address => uint256) internal _balances;

    uint256 public _totalSupply;
    uint8 public _decimals;
    string public _symbol;
    string public _name;
    address public owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        _name = "MyToken";
        _symbol = "MTK";
        _decimals = 0;
        _totalSupply = 1000000;
        _balances[owner] = _totalSupply;

        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the event `Transfer` has the amount **indexed**. This is a patter of ERC721 and not ERC20.

Consider changing:

```js
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 indexed value);
```

to:

```js
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
```

Also the same for `Approval`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I set them as  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);